# What is the purpose of the ‘:list’ and ‘:print’ commands in Vim?

Tags: vim

Not looking for the help file, more for the motivation why would one use these commands?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't recall *ever* using `:list` in over a dozen years of Vim use.

`:print` I use often in this form:

```
:g/re/p
```

Where `re` is a regular expression. Handy for seeing where a string appears in a file without having to move through it.

`:list` looks neat, though. Perhaps I should `:s/p/l/` in the previous command. :-)

Comment: I rather use `:#`, which also allows seeing line numbers.

Answer (score 2):

I use `:print` occasionally when I want to print only a chunk of code. If you have a block of text being visually selected, the command will operate only on what is selected.

The `:list` command does the same thing, but makes an effort to output things like control characters in a more readable fashion.

Answer (score 0):

I think those are simply old Ex commands, originating from the original vi. It’s useful if you use Ex mode often (see `:help Ex-mode`). But I use them very seldom.